# How to implement MarkerOptions in Parcelable Object

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, parcelable, parcel

I've a class that is Parcelable and has some fields.
One of those fields is a MarkerOptions, and I'm trying to find out how I can read and write those MarkerOptions...

I know the [MarkerOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html) class is Parcelable, but I have no clue on how to read and write it from another class...

Let's say I have this class:.

```
public class Foo implements Parcelable {
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private String someField; 

    public Foo() {}

    public Foo(Parcel in) {
        this.markerOptions = in.readParcelable(MarkerOptions.class.getClassLoader());
        this.someField= in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(markerOptions, flags);
        dest.writeString(someField);    
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Foo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Foo>() {
        public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Foo(in); 
        }

        public Foo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Foo[size];
        }
    };
}
```

How can I read and write the MarkerOptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a `Parcelable` to a `Parcel`, [call `writeParcelable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeParcelable%28android.os.Parcelable,%20int%29). To read a `Parcelable` from a `Parcel`, [call `readParcelable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readParcelable%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29).

Comment: I updated my question with writeParcelable() and readParcelable(), could you verify my code will work this way (I can't test it right now)?

Comment: @HansVn: Personally, I'd start with `null` for the parameter to `readParcelable()`, to use the default class loader. Otherwise, this looks OK.